# conda error: could not found url

Tags: macos, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, pypi

recently i installed the anaconda but when i'm open it i got this error: `Error fetching package index
Could not find URL: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osx-64/` also when i'm using the command`conda install ...` i got `Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: .....Error: Could not find URL: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osx-64/`. and i cant install packages.

and this is `conda info`: `platform : osx-64
        conda version : 3.19.1
  conda-build version : 1.19.0
       python version : 3.5.1.final.0
     requests version : 2.9.1
     root environment : //anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : //anaconda
     envs directories : //anaconda/envs
        package cache : //anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osx-64/
                        https://pypi.python.org/pypi/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
                        https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : /Users/saman/.condarc
    is foreign system : False`
.

Answer (score 11):

Edit your file `~/.condarc` and take out the lines that include `pypi.*`. These are not valid conda channels.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved it by applying the following commands in the terminal:

1. conda info
2. cd to config file (cd /Users/select/the/folder/where/config/file/is)
3. open .condarc (textEdit app opened the file automatically)

   From the textEdit: delete https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ and save and
   close .condarc file
4. conda info (to check it deleted it)
5. conda update conda
6. conda update anaconda

Answer (score 1):

Install MiniConda

```
sh Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -f
```

In the same folder of previous  conda
It will solve all conda related problem

Works for me as charm

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the `condarc` file, as mentioned.
It is hidden, thus you may not find it right away.

You can find it like this, from you home folder:

```
find . -name ".condarc"
```

Answer (score 0):

in **osx** El Capitan Version 10.11.6 and **Anaconda 4.1.1** worked:

```
vi ./.condarc
```

[image]

so deleted all what did included **pypi**: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/osx-64/