# Anaconda - HTTPError when Updating

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm getting the following error when I try to run `conda update numpy` (also when running `conda update conda`)

```
Fetching package metadata ............CondaHTTPError: HTTP Error: Could not find URL: https://conda.anaconda.org/condaforge/linux-64/
```

The person in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095385/conda-error-could-not-found-url) had a similar issue, but I didn't find any mistakes in my .condarc similar to theirs.

Here is what my .condarc looks like

```
channels:
  - condaforge
  - bioconda
  - r
  - defaults
```

And the output of `conda info`

```
Current conda install:

           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.2.9
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.2.9
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.5.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.9.1
   root environment : /home/axolotl/miniconda3  (writable)
default environment : /home/axolotl/miniconda3
   envs directories : /home/axolotl/miniconda3/envs
      package cache : /home/axolotl/miniconda3/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/condaforge/linux-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/condaforge/noarch/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/r/linux-64/
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64/
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
        config file : /home/axolotl/.condarc
       offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct channel name is `conda-forge`. You should

```
conda config --remove channels condaforge
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```