# Conda Create Env - CondaHTTPError

Tags: python, conda

I am getting the following error message when using conda to create a new environment.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create -n py3.5_3
Fetching package metadata ..............

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND
for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/t/Go-236a0c7c-5d96-4f63-9b72-b80b4b61c628/win-32/repodata.json>

The remote server could not find the channel you requested.

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show` to view your configuration's current state.
Further configuration help can be found at <http://conda.pydata.org/docs/config.html>.
```

I don't know why this is not working and have looked at the conda config html page without being able to figure out a solution.
I don't what the error message is asking of me or how to fix the HTTP error. I presume that I need to update to some new repository addresses or something like that. Any help or solutions from past experience is most welcome.
Below is the output from my conda info command

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda info -a
Current conda install:

               platform : win-32
          conda version : 4.2.12
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.2.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.12.0
       root environment : C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3  (writable)
    default environment : C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3
       envs directories : C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\envs
          package cache : C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\pkgs
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/dsm/win-32
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/dsm/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/win-32
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/noarch



                          https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-32
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch

         https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-32
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
            config file : C:\Users\David\.condarc
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
py2.7                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\envs\py2.7
py3.5                    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\envs\py3.5
py3.5_2                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\envs\py3.5_2
root                  *  C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3

sys.version: 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (defau...
sys.prefix: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3
sys.executable: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\python.exe
conda location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda
conda-build: None
conda-env: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-env.exe
conda-server: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda-server.exe
user site dirs:

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python35\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

License directories:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Miniconda3\licenses
    C:\Users\David\.continuum
    C:\Users\David\AppData\Roaming\Continuum
License files (license*.txt):
Package/feature end dates:
```

Comment: I notice you have too few args.  You will need to specify a python version to download, e.g.  `conda create -n py3.5_3 python=3.5`.  See if this works.

Comment: No, it does not. I get the same response whether I provide a python version or not. I believe that the python command line argument is only required if you want to specify a particular version of python and not the default version installed with miniconda.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the answer to your problem lies in the blank space in the channel URL's list. Did you remove any URL's for us not to see? it looks like you may have....see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095385/conda-error-could-not-found-url) for a solution that could work for you if my hunch is right